# How to plot specific lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Here is a sample of data points:

```
{{1}, {10.7316, 0.00084028}, {10.7313, 0.011671}, {10.7307, 
0.0224732}, {10.7298, 0.033228}, {10.7287, 0.0439166}, {10.7274, 
0.0545204}, {10.7258, 0.0650205}, {10.724, 0.0753987}, {10.7219, 
0.0856364}, {10.7196, 0.0957157}, {10.7171, 0.105619}, {10.7144, 
0.115327}, {10.7115, 0.124825}, {10.7083, 0.134094}, {10.705, 
0.143117}, {10.7014, 0.151879}, {10.6977, 0.160363}, {10.6937, 
0.168553}, {10.6896, 0.176434}, {10.6853, 0.183992}, {10.6809, 
0.191212}, {10.6762, 0.198081}, {10.6715, 0.204584}, {10.6666, 
0.210709}, {10.6615, 0.216444}, {10.6564, 0.221776}, {10.6511, 
0.226696}, {10.6457, 0.231192}, {10.6402, 0.235255}, {10.6347, 
0.238874}, {10.629, 0.242042}, {10.6233, 0.244751}, {10.6175, 
0.246994}, {10.6117, 0.248763}, {10.6059, 0.250054}, {10.6, 
0.250861}, {10.594, 0.25118}, {10.5881, 0.251008}, {10.5822, 
0.250341}, {10.5762, 0.249179}, {10.5703, 0.24752}, {10.5644, 
0.245363}, {10.5586, 0.24271}, {10.5527, 0.239562}, {10.547, 
0.235922}, {10.5412, 0.231793}, {10.5356, 0.227179}, {10.53, 
0.222085}, {10.5245, 0.216518}, {2}, {10.732, -0.0208292}, 
{10.7328, -0.0316198}, {10.7342, -0.0423423}, {10.736, -0.0529679}
{10.7384, -0.0634674}, {10.7414, -0.0738122}, {10.7449, -0.083974},
{10.7489, -0.0939249}, {10.7534, -0.103637}, {10.7585, -0.113084}, 
{10.7641, -0.122238}, {10.7702, -0.131074}, {10.7769, -0.139566}, 
{10.7841, -0.147689}, {10.7918, -0.155419}, {10.8, -0.162733}, 
{10.8088, -0.169607}, {10.8181, -0.176018}, {10.8279, -0.181946}, 
{10.8382, -0.18737}, {10.8491, -0.192269}, {10.8604, -0.196623}, 
{10.8723, -0.200414}, {10.8847, -0.203623}, {10.8976, -0.206234},
{10.911, -0.208228}, {10.9249, -0.20959}, {10.9392, -0.210304}, 
{10.9541, -0.210354}, {10.9695, -0.209727}, {10.9854, -0.208408},
{11.0018, -0.206384}, {11.0186, -0.203641}, {11.0359, -0.200168},
{11.0538, -0.195951}, {11.072, -0.19098}, {11.0908, -0.185243}, 
{11.11, -0.178728}, {11.1297, -0.171425}, {11.1499, -0.163323}, 
{11.1705, -0.154413}, {11.1916, -0.144684}, {11.2132, -0.134125},
{11.2351, -0.122728}, {11.2576, -0.110483}, {11.2805, -0.0973792},
{11.3038, -0.0834078}, {11.3276, -0.068559}, {11.3518, -0.0528232}, 
{3}, {10.7316, 0.00184063}, {10.7313, 0.0126707}, {10.7307, 0.0234714},
{10.7298, 0.0342238}, {10.7287, 0.0449091}, {10.7274, 0.0555085}, 
{10.7258, 0.0660035}, {10.724, 0.0763756}, {10.7219, 0.0866065}, 
{10.7197, 0.096678}, {10.7172, 0.106572}, {10.7144, 0.116272}, 
{10.7115,  0.125759}, {10.7083, 0.135017}, {10.705, 0.144029}, 
{10.7014, 0.152778}, {10.6977, 0.161249}, {10.6938, 0.169426}, 
{10.6897, 0.177293}, {10.6854, 0.184837}, {10.6809, 0.192042}, 
{10.6763, 0.198894}, {10.6716, 0.205382}, {10.6667, 0.211491}, 
{10.6616, 0.217209}, {10.6565, 0.222525}, {10.6512, 0.227428}, 
{10.6459, 0.231907}, {10.6404, 0.235953}, {10.6349, 0.239556}, 
{10.6292, 0.242707}, {10.6235, 0.2454}, {10.6178, 0.247626}, 
{10.612, 0.249379}, {10.6062, 0.250654}, {10.6003, 0.251446}, 
{10.5944, 0.25175}, {10.5885, 0.251563}, {10.5826, 0.250883}, 
{10.5767, 0.249708}, {10.5708, 0.248036}, {10.5649, 0.245868}, 
{10.5591, 0.243205}, {10.5533, 0.240048}, {10.5476, 0.236399}, 
{10.5419, 0.232263}, {10.5363, 0.227642}, {10.5307, 0.222544}, 
{10.5252, 0.216973}}
```

In fact there are three sub-lists. Note the three integers 1, 2 and 3 indicating the beginning of each sub-list. Please note that the real data file contains about 1000 sub-lists.

My questions are the following:

(a). How to `ListPlot` all three sub-lists together in a single plot with option `Joined -> True`. Of course the last point of sub-list 1 should not be connected with the first point of sub-list 2, etc.

(b). Is there a way to pick and `ListPlot` with `Joined -> True` let's say sub-list 1 or sub-lists 1 and 3 together?

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do something like `{l1, l2, l3} = Reap[Module[{idx = 0},
     Scan[If[MatchQ[#, {_Integer}], idx++, Sow[#, idx]] &, 
      lists]]][[2]];` where *list* is your list, then treat the *l1,l2,l3...* as desired in the `ListPlot`

Comment: Alternatively, you can also obtain your lists free of the headers as follows: `{list1, list2, list3} = SplitBy[list, Dimensions][[2 ;; ;; 2]]`

Comment: @MarcoB: Clever.

Comment: @ciao The real data file contains about 1000 sub-lists. So, I need a more automatic solution for plotting all the sub-lists together or picking some of them (let's say 1, 48 and 521).

Comment: @MarcoB Please see the above comment. My problem is not how to remove the headers.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z: Take @MarcoB's method, like so: `l=SplitBy[list, Dimensions][[2 ;; ;; 2]]`. Then, in your plot, use it like `l[[1]]` or `l[[{1,3,5]]` for example single/set. It's a clever and quick method. BTW - Marco and I assumed the headers are consecutive integers...

Comment: @ciao And if I want to plot all 1000 sub-lists together?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z *l*…

Comment: @ciao I did not understand your last comment. What do you mean by /... ?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z If you use Marcos' method as I commented, *l* is all the lists.   l[[x]] is list x, l[[{a,b,c...}]] is lists *a,b,c...*

Comment: @ciao I understand what you mean but if there are 1000 sub-lists surely I cannot write l[[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,... up to 1000}]]! There must be another clever way to do the job.

Comment: *l*… or am I getting trolled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the comments from @MarcoB and @ciao I found a working solution.

```
l = SplitBy[data, Dimensions][[2 ;; ;; 2]];
n = Length[l];
data2 = l[[n]];
L0 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, Joined -> True]
```

Now if we want to plot the sub-list with odd or even headers we take

```
rg = Range[n];
odds = rg[[;; ;; 2]]
evens = rg[[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split data into sublists of runs of successive elements with the same length and group them in pairs

```
SplitBy[data, Length] // Partition[#, 2, 2] &
```

then build rules `{{1}-> sublist1, {2}->sublist2,..., {n}->sublistn}`

```
Map[Rule[Flatten[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] &, SplitBy[data, Length] // Partition[#, 2, 2] &]
```